# Make a string with every every command line argument

Tags: c, string, arguments, argv

I am trying to make (in C) a string that would contain every command line argument, with spaces between them. What I wrote is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    char * str = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
    * str = 'n';
    * (str + 1) = '\0';
    if (argc != 1){
        int istr = 0;
        int iarg = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char) * (strlen(str) + strlen(argv[i]) + 1));
            while (iarg < strlen(argv[i])){
                str[istr] = argv[i][iarg];
                istr++;
                iarg++;
            }
            istr++;
            str[istr] = ' ';
            iarg = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it does not work, and adding prints do not help me to undrestand why. Do you see the problem(s) ?

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Since you don't have any print statements, this code will of course not print anything. So how do you know it does not work?

Comment: @klutt I deleted the printf statement, so that there is only what we need to understand what i try do do.

Comment: Please read about [mre]. The code you are supplying is supposed to demonstrate the problem when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the allocated memory seems to be zeroed out (or atleast having zero after your copied string), and you putting your `' '` after the string terminating `'\0'` this way. Therefore the string is terminated after the first argument and printing it will only show the first arg, also `strlen` will return the number of characters until this `'\0'`. Change this

```
istr++;              // skipping the terminating '\0'
str[istr] = ' ';     // writing ' ' after it
```

to

```
str[istr++] = ' ';   // overwriting the terminating '\0' by ' '
str[istr] = '\0';    // terminating the string
```

Also change this

```
(strlen(str) + strlen(argv[i]) + 1)
```

to

```
(strlen(str) + strlen(argv[i]) + 2)
```

So there is enough space for the `' '` and the terminating `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

Heyho

Inspired by your idea here is a version i wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");

    if (argc <= 1) return 1; // exit if no args

    printf("arguments detected\n");

    size_t size = 2; // start with size 2 for \n (newline) and \0 (terminator)

    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        size += strlen(argv[i]) + 1;
        //some debug output for understanding
        printf("\t%s is %i\n", argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));
    }
    //getting the size

    printf("All arguments added are %i long\n", size);

    char * final_str = malloc(size); //malloc new string
    int offset = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){ // for all args
        int len = strlen(argv[i]); // get length of string
        memcpy(&final_str[offset], argv[i], len); // copy arg into finalstring at offset
        offset +=len + 1; // increment offset by length of string and 1 bnus for space
        final_str[offset-1] = ' '; // add space
    }
    final_str[size-2] = '\n'; //add the last 2 elements
    final_str[size-1] = '\0';
    //print
    printf("%s", final_str);

    return 0;
}
```

I hope it helps.

PS:
Pls dont use * (str+1) = ...; use str[1] = ...; it is more easier to understand